# Only IE auto submits login form for MVC website

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, authentication

I have created an MVC website where users can log on and look at certain information. The problem I am facing is with Internet Explorer, this is the only browser that decides to auto submit the login form when the user navigates to the login page (they must have the details saved from a previous log on).

The login page will sit there for about a second and then automatically submit.

I have confirmed (using jquery) that the auto complete fills in the fields and triggers a click on the submit button (again, only in IE).

The website does NOT use windows authentication and is a simple cookie driven username and password login form.

My question is what could be submitting the form and how can I stop this?

I do not really know what code to provide as extra information so if you need any more information, just ask.

Comment: Start>Run>iexplore.exe -extoff - the first step in testing ALL web browser issues (not just in IE) is to test in no Addons mode. Common form filling addons for IE are the Google Toolbar or RoboForm.

Comment: You were bang on, it was a Hewlett Packard addon called "SimplePass". Knew I was looking in the wrong places. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step in troubleshooting ALL web browsers is to test in no Addons mode. For IE testing, go Start>Run>iexplore.exe -extoff [url].